# SpringBootTest not loading @Component

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a component class that initializes the entity model:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DefaultEntityGenerator {
    private final SpringLiquibase springLiquibase;
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws LiquibaseException {
       // create default entities
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using Lombok, so the reference to springLiquibase is effectively an @Autowired field (just provided on the constructor).

This gets picked up properly with a regular application launch, and the default entities do get created.

During testing, though, the DefaultEntityGenerator component is not getting instantiated.

Here's how I have my test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ProductServiceTests {

// This really shouldn't be necessary
//    @Autowired
//    private DefaultEntityGenerator defaultEntityGenerator;
    
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
}
```

If I remove the comments, then the component gets created and initialized - but I don't understand why I should have to explicitly create a reference like this.  I don't have to do this in a regular launch.

Is this just regular SpringBootTest behavior (only referenced beans get constructed during test)?  Or am I doing something wrong with this component?

Comment: How do you approve that the bean is not get constructed when the @Autoware is commented?

Comment: I set a breakpoint and run the tests in debug.  Or I add log output and confirm that it isn't showing.  Or I check the database for the default entities that should be created and see that they are not present.  All of these show that the component is not getting created/initialized.

Comment: This shall not be the default behavior of SpringBootTest. I tested it and without the `@Autowired` things, the component was created. I doubt that there is something wrong with your project structure, you may add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)` with your `@SpringBootTest` annotation, in which the `Application.class` is the entry for your application.

Comment: @Lebecca unfortunately, adding classes = MyApplicatoin.class does not help.  The `@component` does not get instantiated during test.

Comment: You may create a minimal project to reproduce the problen and submit it to github so others can have a look at where the problem really is

Comment: Or you can try to remove the liquid dependency, just print something in the post construct method, and to see whether the test is executed as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The problem was that lazy-initialization had been set to true in our test profile:

spring:
main:
lazy-initialization: true